# Reference control using string instead ID

Tags: android, reference, controls

Typical way to reference android control is something like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
```

Where R.id.tv is integer referencing my xml control.

The thing is I would like to make reference using string "R.id.tv". Is that possible?

Let's say I have multiple controls:

```
tv1,
tv2,
tv3,
tv4,
tv5,
```

How would I put this into some sort of loop and interate through controls. I am thinking I would use loop counter to reference different controls. How's that to be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question:

- [Using findviewbyid with a string in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865244/android-using-findviewbyid-with-a-string-in-a-loop)

Comment: thank you. I was looking at getIdentifier but I wasn't quite sure how to use it properly. Example you linked illustrates exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to put the ids into an array and reference by subscript.

```
int[] ids = { R.id.tv1, R.id.tv2 /* etc. */ };
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try next

```
private int getIdResourceByName(String aString)
{
  String packageName = "com.myProject.myPackage"; // set your package name here
  int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "id", packageName);
  return resId;
}
```

...

```
  for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++) {
      TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(getIdResourceByName("tv" + Integer.toString(i)));
      ...
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you'd want to do this, it's pretty ugly, inefficient, and likely to cause maintenance issues and bugs.

Why not use a collection (e.g. ArrayList) to store references to all the controls?