# Is there a way to get 10 or more ID on android studio without doing manually?

Tags: android, checkbox

im doing a application to see if a checkedBox is checked,
But i have 21 checkbox, and i need to get the id of all checkbox to make an operation.

Is there a way to get all id to an array without doing it manually?
i mean without doing the cast 21 times.~
like this.

CheckBox MineBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id. "");
i dont want to do this.
plis help me

Comment: Have a look at Butter Knife: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Using findViewById() with a string / in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865244/android-using-findviewbyid-with-a-string-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could wrap your Checkboxes in a RecyclerView?
 Elsewise.. here is the code, but it's really ugly, and be careful with naming conventions for your Checkboxes in xml. (here: android:id = "@+id/checkBox0"

```
CheckBox[] checkBoxList = new CheckBox[20];

for (int i = 0; i < 20, i++){
    String checkBoxID = "checkBox" + i;
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(checkBoxID, "id", "com.your.projectname");
    checkBoxList[i] = findViewById(resID);

}
```

Comment: CheckBoxList[i] = findViewByid(resID); i got an erro here

Comment: Make sure that you are naming your Checkboxes correctly in your xml - especially check the small/capital letters.
If you are calling this inside a special view, you'll need to call findViewById on it. Have you changed the package name correctly?

Comment: I think you'll need to cast your View to Checkbox on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for(int i=0; i<xvalue; i++) {
   for(int j=0; j<yvalue; j++) {
    String checkID = "chk" + i + "-" + j;
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(checkID, "id", "com.xx.xx");
    checks[i][j] = ((Button) findViewById(id));
    checks[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
   }
}
```