# EditText in GridView get Data and into an array

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-gridview

I want to display several edit texts in a grid view.
 `package       com.devan.test1;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
private final String[] web;
View grid;
private Context mContext;

public CustomGrid(Context c, String[] web) {
    mContext = c;

    this.web = web;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return web.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
        EditText textView = (EditText) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);


    } else {
        grid = convertView;
    }

    return grid;
}
}`
```

The adapter which I made works but what I don't know is how to get data from several edit texts and store into an array.
Regards Devan
**Update**
MainActivtiy.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GridView grid;
String[] web = {
        "Google",
        "Github",
        "Instagram",
        "Facebook",
        "Flickr",
        "Pinterest",
        "Quora",
        "Twitter",
        "Vimeo",
        "WordPress",
        "Youtube",
        "Stumbleupon",
        "SoundCloud",
        "Reddit",
        "Blogger"

};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web);
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public  void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("l",adapter.getBundle());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grid"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    />

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grid"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main2Activity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tc1);
    t.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("l"));
}
}
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.devan.test1.Main2Activity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tc1"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

grid_single.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />


   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865244/android-using-findviewbyid-with-a-string-in-a-loop). One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4865350/8082357) suits your needs well.

What you would do is the following: You name your edit fields following a certain pattern like *edittext[number]* where *[number]* is between 0 and the number of edit texts minus 1. The answer suggests how to loop through all these fields. Using the *getText* function of the edit texts you can get the entered text and add it to an array / list.

Here's some code how you can achieve that:

```
String idPrefix = "edittext_";
final int NUMBER_OF_EDIT_TEXTS = 5; // You might want to retrieve this value from some array / list size
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_EDIT_TEXTS; i++) {
  int resID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(idPrefix + i, "id", getPackageName());
  EditText edt = (EditText) grid.findViewById(resId);
  String text = edit.getText();
  // Do something with text
}
```

Comment: @patrik what values should I use for' some_value' and 'some_other_value' variables in that loop. I didn't understand it well.Coud you post me a sample code.

Comment: I updated my answer and added some code, hope it helps.

Comment: @patrik You told to name the edittexts. How should I do that. Should I post other files too.

Comment: At some point you must create the edit texts. Either statically in an XML layout or dynamically using (Java) code. Do you have that?

Comment: I have edited my post. Hope it helps you to answer my questions. If have any queries regarding my files please ask.

Comment: From your newly-added code I cannot see whether all EditTexts are generated or not. Does it work that you see all EditTexts you want to provide to the user?

Comment: Yes patriknow the grid view shows all the edit texts that I want to show to the iser