# Find button by ID in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a user interface with multiple buttons. They have the IDs "button1", "button2", ...
I want to set an OnClickListener for all of them in a for loop. I dont want to type a line like button1.setOnClickListener for every button.

I have found one solution that works in java here: [Android: Using findViewById() with a string / in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865244/android-using-findviewbyid-with-a-string-in-a-loop)
And I tried to adapt it in Kotlin.

```
var buttons = ArrayList<Button>()
for (i in 1..7) {
    var idString = "Button%i"
    var buttonID = getResources().getIdentifier(idString, "id", packageName)
    buttons.add( findViewWithTag(buttonID))
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(buttonclicked)
}
```

This throws an "Unresolved Reference" error. How can I access all buttons without typing a line for each of them?
Thanks in advance to all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `findViewWithTag()` instead of `findViewById()` in your code.
Also you are not doing string interpolation correctly by `var idString = "Button%i"`.
Change to this:

```
val buttons = ArrayList<Button>()
for (i in 1..7) {
    val idString = "Button$i"
    val buttonID = resources.getIdentifier(idString, "id", packageName)
    buttons.add(findViewById(buttonID))
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(buttonclicked)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the packageName?

Comment: It is the application's package name: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName()