# Get Ids Dynamically using findViewById() in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

In my `XML` layout I have some `TextView` with `ids` like slot0, slot1...slot15.
Is there any way to generate the corresponding `Id` dynamically in java like the following?
`findViewById(R.id.*customStringForId*)`
then access each of `TextView` using a `for` loop?

I am currently unable to use `findViewById(R.id.*customStringForId*)` because I can't find it in the `XML`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4865244

Answer (score 1):

Thats a bad practice for access component from your xml

You need set manual for id with findViewById for tell java class if in your xml there existing textview with id which already you set and give you access for do whatever like implement onclick event, settext, etc.

If you cant find your id, you need check if setContentView in your java point to your xml.

Answer (score 0):

there are some ways to solve your problem but you should write your layout in the question to let us know how you design the layout.
**But** for example if you have a list of `TextViews` inside layout like the following:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/slot0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="example" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/slot1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="example" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/slot2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="example" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

you can access the `TextView` Dynamically via the layout like the following:

```
public TextView getTextView(int index){
        return ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout)).getChildAt(index)
}
```